# NullPointerException on ProgressDialog

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, progressdialog

I'm getting a NullPointerException while using a progress dialog.

My code is as follows:

```
package org.text.me.actionBar.edit.fragments;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.quickblox.core.QBCallback;
import com.quickblox.core.QBCallbackImpl;
import com.quickblox.core.result.Result;
import com.quickblox.module.content.QBContent;
import com.quickblox.module.content.model.QBFile;
import com.quickblox.module.content.result.QBFileUploadTaskResult;
import com.quickblox.module.users.QBUsers;
import com.quickblox.module.users.model.QBUser;
import org.text.me.R;
import org.text.me.actionBar.definitions.Queries;
import org.text.me.actionBar.edit.activity.ChangeNameActivity;
import org.text.me.actionBar.edit.activity.ChangePasswordActivity;
import org.text.me.actionBar.gallery.activity.GalleryActivity;
import org.text.me.actionBar.holder.DataHolder;
import org.text.me.actionBar.utils.bitmap.BitmapUtility;
import org.text.me.actionBar.utils.external_storage.ExternalStorageUtils;

import java.io.File;

import static android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER;
import static org.text.me.actionBar.definitions.Constants.TAG;
import static org.text.me.actionBar.preferences.SharedConstants.*;
import static org.text.me.actionBar.preferences.SharedPrefs.*;

public class EditProfileFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, QBCallback {

private View        editProfileView;
private ImageView   ivProfilePicture;
private TextView    tvFullName;
private ImageButton ibPassword;
private ImageButton ibName;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private String fullName = null;

private Bitmap DEFAULT_PROFILE_PICTURE = null;
private Bitmap PROFILE_PICTURE         = null;

private static       int                   DEFAULT_WIDTH            = 300;
private static       int                   DEFAULT_HEIGHT           = 250;
private static final int                   DEFAULT_COMPRESS_QUALITY = 100;
private static final Bitmap.CompressFormat DEFAULT_COMPRESS_FORMAT  = Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG;
private static final boolean               fileIsPublic             = false;

public static EditProfileFragment getInstance () {
    return new EditProfileFragment ();
}

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    setHasOptionsMenu ( false );
}

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    editProfileView = inflater.inflate ( R.layout.fragment_edit_profile, container, false );

    setupUi ();
    setupProgressDialog ();

    return editProfileView;
}

private void setupUi () {
    tvFullName = (TextView) editProfileView.findViewById ( R.id.tvName );
    ivProfilePicture = (ImageView) editProfileView.findViewById ( R.id.ivEditProfilePicture );
    ibPassword = (ImageButton) editProfileView.findViewById ( R.id.ibPassword );
    ibName = (ImageButton) editProfileView.findViewById ( R.id.ibName );

    tvFullName.setText ( getStringPrefs ( getActivity (), SIGN_IN_USER_FULL_NAME ) );

    if ( getStringPrefs ( getActivity (), PROFILE_PICTURE_PATH ).equals ( null ) )
        setupDefaultProfilePicture ();
    else
        setupProfilePicture ();


    ibName.setOnClickListener ( this );
    ibPassword.setOnClickListener ( this );
    ivProfilePicture.setOnClickListener ( this );
}

private void setupProgressDialog () {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog ( editProfileView.getContext () );
    progressDialog.setMessage ( getResources ().getString ( R.string.loading ) );
    progressDialog.setCancelable ( false );
}

private void setupDefaultProfilePicture () {
    DEFAULT_PROFILE_PICTURE = BitmapUtility.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource (
            getResources (),
            R.drawable.action_people,
            DEFAULT_WIDTH,
            DEFAULT_HEIGHT );
    ivProfilePicture.setScaleType ( FIT_CENTER );
    ivProfilePicture.setImageBitmap ( DEFAULT_PROFILE_PICTURE );
}

private void setupProfilePicture () {
    if ( PROFILE_PICTURE != null ) PROFILE_PICTURE.recycle ();

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options ();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inInputShareable = true;
    options.inDither = false;
    options.inSampleSize = 8;
    PROFILE_PICTURE = BitmapFactory.decodeFile ( getStringPrefs ( getActivity (), PROFILE_PICTURE_PATH ),
                                                 options );
    ivProfilePicture.setImageBitmap ( PROFILE_PICTURE );

    if ( !getBooleanPrefs ( getActivity (), IS_PROFILE_UPLOADED ) && !getStringPrefs ( getActivity (),
                                                                                       PROFILE_PICTURE_PATH )
            .equals ( null ) ) {

        progressDialog.show ();

        File profilePicture = ExternalStorageUtils.saveBitmapToFile ( PROFILE_PICTURE, DEFAULT_COMPRESS_FORMAT,
                                                                      DEFAULT_COMPRESS_QUALITY,
                                                                      String.valueOf ( getIntPrefs ( getActivity
                                                                                                             (),
                                                                                                     SIGN_IN_USER_ID ) ) );
        QBContent.uploadFileTask ( profilePicture, fileIsPublic, new QBCallbackImpl () {
            @Override
            public void onComplete (Result result) {
                if ( result.isSuccess () ) {
                    //Get the uploaded file
                    QBFileUploadTaskResult taskResult = (QBFileUploadTaskResult) result;
                    QBFile file = taskResult.getFile ();
                    int uploadedFileId = file.getId ();

                    //Connect image to user
                    QBUser user = new QBUser ();
                    user.setId ( getIntPrefs ( getActivity (), SIGN_IN_USER_ID ) );
                    user.setFileId ( uploadedFileId );

                    QBUsers.updateUser ( user, new QBCallbackImpl () {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete (Result result) {
                            if ( result.isSuccess () ) {
                                Toast.makeText ( getActivity (), getResources ().getString ( R.string
                                                                                                     .action_edit_successful ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
                                progressDialog.dismiss ();
                                setBooleanPrefs ( getActivity (), IS_PROFILE_UPLOADED, true );
                            } else {
                                progressDialog.hide ();
                                Toast.makeText ( getActivity (), result.getErrors ().get ( 0 ).toString (),
                                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
                                Log.e ( TAG, result.getErrors ().toString () );
                            }
                        }
                    } );
                } else {
                    progressDialog.hide ();
                    Toast.makeText ( getActivity (), result.getErrors ().get ( 0 ).toString (),
                                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
                    Log.e ( TAG, result.getErrors ().toString () );
                }
            }
        } );
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick (View v) {
    switch ( v.getId () ) {
        case R.id.ibPassword:
            startActivity ( new Intent ( this.getActivity (), ChangePasswordActivity.class ) );
            break;

        case R.id.ibName:
            startActivity ( new Intent ( this.getActivity (), ChangeNameActivity.class ) );
            break;

        case R.id.ivEditProfilePicture:
            Intent intent = new Intent ( getActivity (), GalleryActivity.class );
            startActivity ( intent );
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onComplete (Result result) {

}

@Override
public void onComplete (Result result, Object query) {
    Queries queryType = (Queries) query;
    if ( result.isSuccess () ) {
        switch ( queryType ) {
            case QUERY_UPDATE_USER_INFO:
                DataHolder.getDataHolder ().getSignInUser ().setFullName ( fullName );
                progressDialog.dismiss ();
                Toast.makeText ( this.getActivity (), getResources ().getString ( R.string
                                                                                          .action_edit_successful ),

                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
                break;
        }
    } else {
        progressDialog.hide ();
        Toast.makeText ( this.getActivity (), result.getErrors ().get ( 0 ).toString (),
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        Log.e ( TAG, result.getErrors ().toString () );
    }
}
}
```

And the error that I am getting is as follows:

```
01-23 07:14:55.524    3126-3126/org.text.me W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting     with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d560)
01-23 07:14:55.574    3126-3126/org.text.me E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.text.me.actionBar.edit.fragments.EditProfileFragment.setupProfilePicture(EditProfileFragment.java:134)
        at org.text.me.actionBar.edit.fragments.EditProfileFragment.setupUi(EditProfileFragment.java:93)
        at org.text.me.actionBar.edit.fragments.EditProfileFragment.onCreateView(EditProfileFragment.java:76)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:843)
        at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1864)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3698)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The program works like a charm if I comment out progressDialog.show()
The error occurs at progressDialog.show(); How can a NullPointerException occur there? And what is the solution to it?

Comment: *Follow the stack trace*. You try to use `progressDialog` in  `setupProfilePicture()` (called from `setupUi()`) before creating it .

Comment: FWIW I see a lot wrong with the code, but I don't see anything particularly wrong with the question. It is _yet another_ "I've got an NPE" question, but it is a complete question.

Comment: @SK9 Not closable anymore, but certainly down-voteable for *research effort*. There's exactly one cause of an NPE and in this case it's blatantly obvious. IMHO, "debug my code for me" should be close-able, but alas, it's not.

Comment: @BrianRoach fair enough, and I'd +1 your view if I could: "\"debug my code for me\" should be close-able".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setupProfilePicture()`, which accesses the `progressDialog` instance and which is still `null`, is ultimately called before `setupProgressDialog()`. Step through the `setupUi()` and `setupProgressDialog()` calls you're making in `onCreateView()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your setupUI method is called before your setupProgressDialog (where the progress dialog is created), and your setupUI method calls setupProfilePicture which tries to use the progress dialog that has not yet been created -- thus the null pointer exception.